# How did i break my tomcat (webapp no longer loads)?

Tags: tomcat

In debugging this: [Why am I getting a 400: bad request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032430/why-am-i-getting-a-400-bad-request)

I somehow broke my embeddable Tomcat.
My webapp is no longer loading at localhost:8080/Archery
Tomcat doesnt spit out anythihng in a browser at that url, it just fails to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it was a simple error, i was setting the header to 204, no content.